# Secure communication + authentification on android server

Tags: android, encryption, client-server, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to implement a server on android which securely communicates with (registered) clients. The protocol is proprietary.
My question is: Is following communication secure?

1. Adding a User:

   - Client requests sign up

     - Server creates public key and sends it to the client.
   - Client encrypts username+password with public key and sends it to the server.

     - Server accepts connection, hashes salted password, stores it in a keystore and
       informs client about accepted sign up. (the decision, if a client will be
       accepted or declined will be made by the user of the phone)
2. Communication for registered users:

   - Client requests service

     - Server creates public key and sends it to the client.
   - Client sends username+password+symmetric communication key to server.

     - Server verifies username and password using stored hash and salt. Server starts
       symmetrically encrypted communication with client.

RSA will be used for asymmetric and AES will be used for symmetric en/decryption.

Comment: How are you defending against MITM attacks?  What if a malicious server intercepts a client request and sends the client its own public key?  Would the client be fooled into using the bad public key to encrypt its username+password and sending that back to the malicious server?

Comment: You are right. I could use self signed certificate. But there is no need for certificates in my application,  because the client and the server are close to the user and the user has to accept incoming connections on the server.